# Top 1 faster if only selecting one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does the database break the selection loop as fast as it has got one record when using Top 1?

So that 
`select top 1 * from customer where cusId = 1234`

is faster than
`select * from customer where cusId = 1234`
?

`cusId` is unique, so does MSSql understand to do it "faster" without `top 1`?

Comment: WITH (FASTFIRSTROW) can help *sometimes*.  It is not uncommon for me to have: WITH (NOLOCK FASTFIRSTROW) when dirty reads are acceptable.

Comment: I suspect you'll have more noticeable performance and maintainability gains by not using * (even if you are actually using all columns) and by referencing customer correctly (dbo.customer), than worrying about adding this meaningless top operator to the query.

Answer (score 4):

If `cusId` is a primary key, both should be the same re: performance.

EDIT:

You are only adding overhead with TOP 1 if you have unique index that will return 1 result anyway.

It will be different if you have order by something than you are interested in only one row.

MORE:

There is no looping involved, unless there is a table scan involved and there is no index at all for `cusId`.  In that case, `TOP 1` can't help you anyway.

Comment: What about when `cusIs` is not a primary key?

Comment: +1 - if you compare execution plans then the 'top' has an extra step but the cost is too small to count.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion `select * from customer where cusId = 1234` will be more faster..b/c it has one operation less to perform than first one...

Comment: True, but the difference is so small (since cusId is unique) which can be ignored.